# zsh: command not found: ls

Tags: function, loops, zsh

I'm having a rather strange problem with zsh.  When I start up my shell, everything - functions, environment vars, aliases, etc. - all work fine.  I've created the following function and sourced it in zsh:

```
clean()
{
    path=/tmp    
    for i in ${path}/*; do
      echo $i
    done
}
```

Running `clean` in the terminal works as expected, in that it prints out all the files in /tmp/.  Afterward, however, trying *any* command - for example, ls - produces this:

```
zsh: command not found: ls
```

I have several other functions that work just fine, which leads me to believe that somehow, that loop is causing the problem.  At any rate, this is very frustrating and I would sincerely appreciate the community's eyes.  Thanks!

Comment: This script doesn't print anything, it just creates a function. Please tell exact steps you take to reproduce the error.

Comment: After creating the function, I simple run `clean` in zsh.  I'll update the post to try to make that clearer.

Comment: Is clean aliased to anything else in your environment before running?

Comment: qor - no.  Even if I change the name of the function to "foobar123," I still get the same problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce - works exactly as expected for me. It must be a problem elsewhere in your environment.

Comment: you should modify your question to have the full code. including that you were messing with $path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is assigning the `path` variable - since zsh has that variable reserved (in addition to PATH), overwriting it removes the ability for the shell to find *any* command.

The correct answer, of course, is to use a variable other than `$path`:

```
local_path=/tmp    
for i in ${local_path}/*; do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: accept your answer. I suspect you were overwriting the PATH variable. which is very important. use a different one that's not already in the env. CLEAN_PATH shouldn't have this affect for example.

Comment: Oh my... how obvious is that.  Thank you. :)

Comment: Try running your original function after `set -x` and see if the trace tells you anything.

Comment: apparently here's the documentation on that http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#SEC98 PATH and path are different but zsh has both and that means you shouldn't mess with them.

Comment: lol, you should accept **my** answer, since I said the same thing a few minutes before...

Answer (score 1):

I guess it overwrites the variable `path`, which is the one used to find commands. That's why it doesn't find commands anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I dugg for hours to find this again. Zsh offer a nice trick to remove duplicates from PATH-type variables, a bit out of topic, but may be useful :

```
typeset -T PYTHONPATH pythonpath
typeset -U pythonpath
```

1. the first line bind PYTHONPATH colon separated string to zsh array
2. the second remove duplicates